# Classic ASP page cannot send message to remote private queue on windows 2008 r2

Tags: iis-7, msmq, windows-server-2008-r2

I have IIS7.5 server (Windows 2008 R2) with a classic ASP page that sends a message to private queue that is located on another Windows 2008 R2 server.

The page refers to queue by its formatname:

`DIRECT=OS:servername\private$\queuename.`

The message is not delivered to the queue.

I checked firewalls - everything is open and nothing of note appears in the event logs on both servers.

If I run the same code in VBS file on iis7 server with the same credentials - the message is delivered to the remote queue.

If I send the message from IIS7 to a queue on Windows 2003 server - everything works just fine.

Additional details: The IIS7 site runs in an application pool with domain user credentials, the same user has full control permissions on the queue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be a permissions issue on the destination queue.
Easy test is to give Everyone and Anonymous Logon full control temporarily to see if messages then get through